# pandas фильтр строк на основе поиска максимума в столбце

Tags: python, pandas

Задача такая. Есть датафрейм:

```
df123 = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["1", "1", "1", "2", "2"],
                      "B": ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "monday", "tuesday"],
                      "C": ["1", "2", "3", "2", "2"]})
```

Нужно для каждого уникального значения колонки А вывести строку с максимальным значением колонки С, при этом колонка В также должна показываться. Если одинаковых максимумов несколько, то нужно показать все сроки с одинаковыми максимумами (они будут отличаться по столбцу В)
Т.е. на выходе должно быть:

[image]

Мне в голову приходит только

```
    df123.groupby('A', as_index = False)\
     .agg({'C' : 'max'})
```

Но тогда теряю колонку В. Чувствую, где-то на поверхности плавает решение, не могу сообразить.

Comment: правила требуют чтобы вы показали собственные попытки решить свою задачу, а если что-то не получается, то сформулировать проблему. в этом случае вам с вашей проблемой помогут

Comment: спасибо, добавил.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, что никто не вспомнил про `merge`:

```py
pd.merge(df123, df123.groupby('A').agg({'C': 'max'}).reset_index(), on=('A','C'))
```

Вывод:

```
    A   B           C 
0   1   wednesday   3
1   2   monday      2
2   2   tuesday     2
```

Работает медленнее, чем решение с `apply`, но возможно в каких-то случаях это решение будет более универсальным.

Comment: Спасибо! У меня этот способ сработал мгновенно, а с apply ни в какую, даже со вторым вариантом.

Comment: На большом датафрейме такая ситуация вполне понятна. Всё же мой способ "векторный", а apply с lambda это построчная обработка, поэтому желательно его избегать на серьёзных датафреймах.

Comment: Не знаю как у кого, но у меня такой вариант     %timeit pd.merge(df123, df123.groupby('A').agg({'C': 'max'}).reset_index(), on=('A','C'))    показал 2.52 ms ± 71.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each). Что как минимум в полтора раза дольше, чем варианты приведенные выше. Поэтому я и не включит его в свой ответ.

Comment: @passant Пробовали с разным кол-вом столбцов и строк? "Боевой" то датафрейм наверняка не такой маленький как в примере и там всё может быть по-другому

Comment: @ CrazyElf да нет, конечно не пробовал. Этим уж пусть ТС занимается. Я просто написал такой оператор, померил, потом вспомнил, что ТС желает скорости и отбросил вариант. Но на реальные цифери посмотреть было бы интересно.

Comment: @passant Ну я тоже сначала на такие замеры полагался. Но видимо с реальным датафреймом расклады уже другие получаются.

Comment: @CrazyElf не даром же есть та самая O() -  метрика в теории алгоритмов. И плохо, когда она какая-нибудь квадратичная  -  т.е. на малых значениях N может быть даже лучше других (например O(NlogN) , а на больших -  становиться неприемлемой.  Но проводить такой анализ для этой задачи - сорри. Если ТС провел такой эксперимент  -  я ему вполне верю, что на его объемах этот алгоритм побеждает.

Answer (score 3):

```
df123.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda t: t[t.C==t.C.max()])
```

Результат:

```
     A          B  C
A                   
1 2  1  wednesday  3
2 3  2     monday  2
  4  2    tuesday  2
```

P.S. Из за жалоб на медленность работы провел эксперимент и с большим удивлением обнаружил, что результат можно немного ускорить за счет весьма незначительной переделки:

```
%timeit df123.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda t: t[t.C==t.C.max()])
```

**1.85 ms** ± 9.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%timeit df123.groupby(['A']).apply(lambda t: t[t.C.values==t.C.values.max()])
```

**1.62 ms** ± 14.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Спасибо. В данном случае работает, но на большом датафрейме (около 100к строк) уходит в глубокую задумчивость.

Comment: На большом датафрейме сработал такой вариант, но он показывает только одно первое вхождение максимума.

    df123.loc[df123.groupby(['A'])['C'].idxmax()]

Т.е. в результате будет:

        A   B         C
    2 1 wednesday 3
    3 2 monday     2

По сути задачу не решает.

Comment: См. дополнения к моему ответу.